# Swift : Delegate is nil

Tags: ios, swift

I've tried to build a delegate design pattern.   I have a simple `delegate` in `WeatherManager` , but it's always `nil`.
I've tried to add `weatherManager.delegate = self` in `override func viewDidLoad()`  of `WeatherViewController`.
However, I have another Protocol and delegate, which works fine.

I'm using the API to obtain geographic coordinates from city names, and the URL of the API to get information about the weather is created and executed.

**WeatherManager**

```
import Foundation

// delegate design parttern

protocol WeatherManagerDelegate:AnyObject {
    func didUpdateWeather(inputWeatherModel: WeatherModel)
}

class WeatherManager {
    
    // delegate
    weak var delegate: WeatherManagerDelegate?
    
    // fetchCoordinate
    func fetchWeather(urlString: String) {
        performRequest(inputURLString: urlString)
    }
    
    // performRequest
    func performRequest(inputURLString: String) {
        // 1. Create URL
        if let url = URL(string: inputURLString) {
            // 2. Create URLSession
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            // 3. Give the URLSession a task
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }
                if let safeData = data {
                    if let weather = self.parseJSON(JSONobject: safeData) {
                        // ---------------- problem here  -------------------
                        self.delegate?.didUpdateWeather(inputWeatherModel: weather)
                    }
                }
            }
            // 4. Start the task
            task.resume()
        }
    }
    
    // parse JSON object
    func parseJSON(JSONobject: Data) -> WeatherModel? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: JSONobject)
            
            let id = decodedData.weather[0].id
            let temp = decodedData.main.temp
            let name = decodedData.name
            
            let weather = WeatherModel(conditionId: id, cityName: name, temperature: temp)
            return weather
            
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }

}
```

**WeatherModel**

```
import Foundation

struct WeatherModel {
    let conditionId: Int
    let cityName: String
    let temperature: Double
    var temperatureString: String {
        return String(format: "%.1f", temperature)
    }
    
    var conditionName: String {
        switch conditionId {
        case 200...232:
            return "cloud.bolt"
        case 300...321:
            return "cloud.drizzle"
        case 500...531:
            return "cloud.rain"
        case 600...622:
            return "cloud.snow"
        case 701...781:
            return "cloud.fog"
        case 800:
            return "sun.max"
        case 801...804:
            return "cloud.bolt"
        default:
            return "cloud"
        }
    }
}
```

**WeatherViewController**

```
import UIKit

class WeatherViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, WeatherManagerDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var conditionImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var temperatureLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cityLabel: UILabel!
    
    let weatherManager = WeatherManager()
    var coordinateManager = CoordinateManager()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        searchTextField.delegate = self
        searchTextField.keyboardType = .asciiCapable
        weatherManager.delegate = self
    }

    @IBAction func searchPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        searchTextField.endEditing(true)
    }
    
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        searchTextField.endEditing(true)
        return true
    }
    
    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField.text != "" {
            return true
        } else {
            textField.placeholder = "Type Something"
            return false
        }
    }
    
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        
        if let city = searchTextField.text {
            coordinateManager.fetchCoordinate(cityName: city)
        }
        searchTextField.text = ""
    }
    
    func didUpdateWeather(inputWeatherModel: WeatherModel) {
        print(inputWeatherModel.temperature)
    }
}
```

**CoordinateManager**

```
import Foundation

struct CoordinateManager {

    // WeatherManager
    let weathetManager = WeatherManager()
    // geographical coordinates(lat, lon)　地理座標
    let coordinateURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?limit=1&appid=c8e60c6317c653a1789294c00f54ae19"
    
    // fetchCoordinate
    func fetchCoordinate(cityName: String) {
        let urlString = "\(coordinateURL)&q=\(cityName)"
        performRequest(inputURLString: urlString)
    }
    
    // transformURLString
    func transformURLString(_ string: String) -> URLComponents? {
        guard let urlPath = string.components(separatedBy: "?").first else {
            return nil
        }
        var components = URLComponents(string: urlPath)
        if let queryString = string.components(separatedBy: "?").last {
            components?.queryItems = []
            let queryItems = queryString.components(separatedBy: "&")
            for queryItem in queryItems {
                guard let itemName = queryItem.components(separatedBy: "=").first,
                      let itemValue = queryItem.components(separatedBy: "=").last else {
                        continue
                }
                components?.queryItems?.append(URLQueryItem(name: itemName, value: itemValue))
            }
        }
        return components!
    }
    
    // performRequest
    func performRequest(inputURLString: String) {
        // 1. Create URL
        let components = transformURLString(inputURLString)
        if let url = components?.url {
            // 2. Create URLSession
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            // 3. Give the URLSession a task
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }
                if let safeData = data {
                    self.parseJSON(JSONobject: safeData)
                }
            }
            // 4. Start the task
            task.resume()
        }
    }

    // parseJSON
    func parseJSON(JSONobject: Data) {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode([CoordinateData].self, from: JSONobject)
            let name = decodedData[0].name
            let lat = decodedData[0].lat
            let lon = decodedData[0].lon
            
            let coordinateModel = CoordinateModel(name: name, lat: lat, lon: lon)
            let weatherURL = coordinateModel.urlString

           // ------- WeatherManager fetchWeather ---------
           weathetManager.fetchWeather(urlString: weatherURL)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

**CoordinateModel**

```
import Foundation

struct CoordinateModel {
    let name: String
    let lat: Double
    let lon: Double
    
    // wheather　地理座標を元に検索した天気の情報
    let weatherstr = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"
    let str = "units=metric&appid=c8e60c6317c653a1789294c00f54ae19#"

    // computedproperty
    var urlString: String {
        return "\(weatherstr)&lat=\(lat)&lon=\(lon)&\(str)"
    }
}
```

Comment: In your code there are two (different) instances of `WeatherManager`, the instance in `WeatherViewController` is unused. You have to set the delegate in `CoordinateManager`

Comment: When you do `WeatherManager()`, it's `WeatherManager.init()`, so it's creating a new object. It's like having two employees, but you manage (be the delegate) of one, and asking yourself why the second one doesn't delete to you. You never set its delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You create a weatherManager in the WeatherViewController , and in the viewDidLoad method you set the WeatherViewController as a delegate to the weatherManager instance you created here. In the CoordinateManager class, you create a new weatherManager, and don't set a delegate for it.

2 solutions, use what is most convenient for you:

1. Create an initializer for the CoordinateManager, to pass it the WeatherManager that you have created and that you are listening to

```
// CoordinateManager class

let weatherManager: WeatherManager

init(weatherManager: WeatherManager) {
   self.weatherManager = weatherManager
}
```

```
// WeatherViewController class

let weatherManager = WeatherManager()
var coordinateManager = CoordinateManager(weatherManager: weatherManager)
```

2. You can directly set WeatherViewController as a delegate to the desired weatherManager instance.

```
// WeatherViewController class

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   searchTextField.delegate = self
   searchTextField.keyboardType = .asciiCapable
   // Instead weatherManager.delegate = self
   coordinateManager.weatherManager.delegate = self
}
```